# vfpages not displaying in content section

Tags: visualforce

[image]I am trying to add custom button of name"move student "on class object to populate the window.but in content part visual force pages are not showing.

please anyone suggest me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are adding in the Parent Object Buttons/Links. Try adding that button on Child Object which you will refer that button on related list under Parent Object. Then you can get the related Visualforce Page that you created in that Content Picklist.

Hope this helps...

**Update:**

In the VF Page, there is a tag starting as "`<Apex:Page>`"

within that tag attributes, there is a "StandardController"

put that as follows

```
<Apex:Page StandardController="Class__c">
```

if you are using **Controller** attribute to access any Apex Class, make that **Controller** to **Extensions** and add the setController in Constructor of Controller Class.

Comment: thank you subash...but as per my requirement i need to create a custom button on class object which will populate a window to move students from one class to another class. soo i creating on class object..

Comment: Use the Standard Controller="YOUR OBJECT(CLASS)" in apex:page tag of the VF page. Then you will get that vf page in that content section

Comment: class is not standard object ,its custom object which i created,

Comment: He means standard controller, not standard object. Two different things.

Comment: yeahhh i tried with that code also but still facing same problem

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: thank you subash,now vf page showing when am selecting detail page buttonoption,but when am selecting list button option vf page not displaying

Comment: Give another attribute called "recordSetVar=Classes" in that apex:page tag and check. It might help you

Comment: Choose this question as solved by clicking on accepting the answer. So that it can be helpful to someone easily

Answer (score 0):

here you go, here try is my visual force page name, and i have provided the id of class so it can redirect from your class record itself, please mark if this helped you [image]